# Is there a limit to how many threads I can make

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok, so I've tagged this question with [java](/questions/tagged/java)  because I'm primarily thinking about it as that is the language I'm writing it currently. However, this is equally as general in the programming world.

My question is: is there any limit to how many threads a processor can handle, and more over what is the likelihood of my application maxing this limit? AND what would happen if I did?

I don't really know much  about threads - I just know that they enable you to execute two processes at once (that's probably not even the correct term). Initially, I thought single core processors didn't allow for multiple threads but then common sense kicked in and I thought about how that couldn't be possible given Windows and things. But now I'm wondering, what is the difference between single core and multi core processors / what do multi core processors allow?

Explanations in the  simplest terms possible would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I imagine this would be different for every CPU, I would suggest creating a increasing number of thread and monitoring how your cpu reacts. Your CPU can probably only run a few thread at a time, but how fast it can context switch will be its real measure of efficiency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A processor can normally run one thread at a time. It can *handle* far more than that, however. When you have several processes running, your processor(s) switches between them very quickly, giving each one a slice of the processor's time. This gives an illusion of concurrency, but really everything is happening in serial.

There is not really a hard limit on the number of threads you can run, but there *is* overhead involved when the processor switches between threads. If you're building an application with a GUI, it's a good idea to spawn a separate thread for long-running tasks so that the GUI can stay responsive. If you expect to run on a computer with multiple processors or some other solution which allows true concurrency, you can try to take advantage of that by running in separate threads, but it does make your problem more complex and can cause bugs which are hard to track down.

Most computers are multi-core today and can actually run several threads concurrently. In fact more concurrency, rather than stronger individual processors, is likely how computers will develop in the future. Being able to take advantage of that *is* important, but it's hard. If you don't have a specific reason to make your application multithreaded, I recommend avoiding it until you feel comfortable doing so.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer - very informative. The whole reason for me asking this question is because I have a recursive method that updates a GUI but I've figured out that I can at least half the time that it takes if I eliminate the GUI bit, so I'm looking to put the GUI bits in a separate thread. AND I think I'm confident enough to do so!

Answer (score 4):

In Java you will hit a limit creating threads when you run out of memory to process them. It took me about 10,000 on 2GiB of RAM to do this. Once you do hit an `OutOfMemoryException` you will have problems unless you already have a shell/Task manager open as you may strugle to kill the JVM process.

In terms of processors, they only run 1 (or 2) per core at a time. It is the job of the scheduler (part of your OS) to allocate time so thread A will run for a little bit, then thread 2 etc. In this way they allow you to do multiple things at a time. If you have a multi-core cpu, the scheduler will also take charge of allocating which thread goes to which core, allowing you to take advantage of this with no extra effort.

In general, you don't need to worry too much about this. Just create multiple threads when you need things to be processed simultaneously (for example, GUI code has to keep processing while background tasks happen). Most appliations have <20 threads anyway.

Comment: 'Most appliations have <20 threads anyway' - and the ones that have more tend to be M$ gunge - 'Windows Sidebar' - 66 threads!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer also - it is too very informative.

Answer (score 2):

> is there any limit to how many threads a processor can handle,

It can only run one or two (with hyperthreading). Some sparc processors can handle up to 16.

It worth remembering this when considering creating lots of threads because creating more than this can be inefficient (esp if the process is cpu bound)

> I just know that they enable you to execute two processes at once

A "process" contains one or more threads. i.e. a "process" has a specific meaning.

> what is the difference between single core and multi core processors / what do multi core processors allow

Multiple cores can run multiple thread concurrently.  A single cores can simulate running multiple threads (fast enough you won't notice)

Provided you have enough threads to use all your cores you can get up to a linear improvement in throughput. e.g. if you can process 10,000 request per second with one core, you might be able to process 80,000 per second with 8 cores.

Comment: "A "process" contains one or more threads. i.e. a "process" has a specific meaning." Not strictly true. In Linux (and I assume, other *Nix systems) each thread is its own process (try creating a few then running `top`)

Comment: @James When I run top on RHEL 5.3 (at least three years old) each process appears once (not for each threads)

Comment: I may be mistaken about top, it may only display the topmost process. Htop certainly displays each thread with its PID (but the same name, memory, etc.)

Comment: @PeterLawrey That view has changed, I remember a time when the threads were not grouped to their parent process. But if you press 'H' when using top you should get a view of the threads.

Comment: The terms Process and Thread are unfortunately treated differently by different authors on the subject. It's like they think concurrency isn't complicated enough already...

Comment: The distinction in Linux is blurred compares with Windows or Solaris. Some operations are purely on a process basis e.g. `kill` kills a process not an individual thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So @JacobRaihle, how should the terms be treated / what are the true definitions?

Comment: @Andy there's not really a 'true' definition I'm aware of, the best you can do is put the word in a context to make the meaning clear.

Comment: @JacobRaihle Ok, thanks. I did find the following top that has a lot of helpful links and answers on: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/2e471d2c-ca0f-44e5-95a1-e9d8a0ec3b94/. Basically though, a process is like a container for the threads. There can be multiple threads in a process that share the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you know that there's only a small (processor dependent) number of threads that can really run *concurrent*. But I suppose that you're asking how many threads can be handled in total (and are switched every now and then).

I think that there might be a limit (depending on operating system and the used hardware) for the  *total* number of threads, but you will most certainly not hit this maximum. Before, you will experience massive performance issues, as (from a specific number of threads on) more threads do not bring more performance, but the opposite.

However, this line, from where on you do not gain any more performance through more parallelism is *not* the number of your cores and instead can be two or four times higher.

Comment: 'Before, you will experience massive performance issues, as (from a specific number of threads on) more threads do not bring more performance, but the opposite' - applies only to CPU-bound threads where the dataset operated on by each thread requires a substantial cache-flush.  On a typical desktop system, eg. that I'm using now, I have 0 threads in that state out of a total of 1072.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @aRestless. I think I understand what you are saying!

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there any limit to how many threads a processor can handle?
```

1) Your computer can execute concurrently as many RUNNING threads as there are cores in the available CPUs.

2) If there are more threads requiring execution than there are cores, the OS applies a scheduling alorithm to decide which set of threads to run after any hardware interrupt or system call that enters the OS and changes the set of threads requiring execution.

3) Thread that are not running/ready to run, ie. are waiting on I/O or each other, are just dead code/stack space in virtual memory and so incur no direct overhead.

Summary:

The limit of running threads that the processor can handle is the same as the number of cores.

The OS/memory system limits the total number of threads in any state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, a nice summary. Although, some other people have put that each core can handle "one (or two)" threads whereas you have only said that a core can handle one. Why is this?

Comment: @Andy Newer processors have Hyperthreading. While I do not understand the details, it effectively allows your processor to act like it has twice as many cores as it actually does. For example, an average intel i3 processor has 2 physical cores, and you would expect it to run 2 threads. But, due to hyperthreading, it can run 4. It even appears to the OS as 4 cores (e.g. when viewed in a system mnitor), each of which can operate independently. However, to the average application developer this is again not something to worry too much about.

Comment: @James Thanks for that information. I will look up Hyperthreading